GAM(M) for longitudinal measurements from paired control treatment samples in R
I have a test dataset  looking like;



ID
Sample
Group
Week




X1
Sample1
Healthy
0


X1
Sample2
Disease
0


X1
Sample3
Healthy
2


X1
Sample4
Disease
2


X1
Sample5
Healthy
5


X1
Sample6
Healthy
16


X1
Sample7
Disease
16


X2
Sample8
Healthy
0


X2
Sample9
Disease
0


X2
Sample10
Healthy
2


X2
Sample11
Disease
2


X2
Sample12
Healthy
5


X2
Sample13
Disease
5


X2
Sample14
Healthy
16


X2
Sample15
Disease
16


X3
Sample16
Healthy
0


X3
Sample17
Disease
0


X3
Sample18
Healthy
2


X3
Sample19
Disease
2


X3
Sample20
Healthy
5


X3
Sample21
Disease
5


X3
Sample22
Healthy
16


X3
Sample23
Disease
16


X4
Sample24
Disease
0


X4
Sample25
Healthy
2


X4
Sample26
Disease
2


X4
Sample27
Healthy
5


X4
Sample28
Disease
5


X4
Sample29
Healthy
16


X4
Sample30
Disease
16



The ID columns define each subject that paired samples collected from. There are total of four time points; 0, 2, 5, and 16.
As some part of the data were exampled above, I have 200 different log-transformed measurements taken from each paired sites at each time point, but not all subjects have complete sample sets. Assuming the measurements are not following linear trend, can you please suggest (to someone who is pretty new to the GAMs/GAMMs) how can I perform testing whether measurements have significantly different longitudinal trend between healthy and disease groups by taking care of the paired sampling strategy using GAM or GAMMs in R?
PS: I tried some models such as
gam(Measurement1 ~ Group + Week +
            s(ID, bs = 're'),
          data = data, method = 'REML')

but I need some other families to test rather than Gaussian.

To clarify: does each ID  represent an individual, and the Healthy/Disease Group represent two distinct (anatomical) sites on the same individual? And are there only 4 time points (at most) for each individual? Please provide that information by editing the question directly, as comments on this site are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Edits were made, thank you

You probably don't need a generalized additive model (GAM) for this study.
A smooth in a GAM can nicely handle a nonlinear association between a predictor and an outcome when your knowledge of the subject matter doesn't suggest a particular functional form. For example, if you had a large number of time points varying among subjects, a GAM for time (perhaps in the simple form of a restricted cubic spline) could be a good choice.
The model you propose, however, doesn't even include Week in a GAM smooth term. The way the model is written, you are assuming a strictly linear association between Week and your outcome. Without an interaction between Week and Group, you are further assuming that the only difference between the Group values is in the intercepts, not in the slopes.
As there are only 4 distinct Week values and two Group values in your data, there wouldn't be much to gain here by using a GAM smooth for Week and its interaction with Group. You can include Group and Week as fixed effects, along with a term for their interaction, to capture the fundamental structure of your data.
With such a model and default coding of predictors:

the intercept will be the estimated outcome at Week0 for the reference level of Group;
the Group coefficient will represent the difference between groups at Week0;
the Week coefficients will be the differences from Week0 associated with the other Week values, for the reference level of Group
the interaction coefficients will document whether there are differences over time between the healthy and disease groups, evaluating whether the Group difference is significant at each Week.

You do need to handle the within-individual correlations. Instead of the s(ID, bs = 're') term used for that in the gam() function of the R mgcv package, you could proceed instead with a mixed model with random effects for ID, or with a generalized least squares model if you have a reasonably well behaved continuous outcome measure. If you do have a reasonably well behaved continuous outcome measure, you won't need to use a generalized linear model with a family different from Gaussian.
Chapter 7 of Frank Harrell's Regression Modeling Strategies provides a useful overview of longitudinal data analysis. Although the emphasis is on generalized least squares, it nicely outlines the principles and the strengths and weaknesses of different approaches.
